# Use S3 for website in multi-regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I want to host my website in S3 (because it seems cheaper and i don't have server side script). I have a domain, and i want my domain link to my S3 website. So far, what i do is enabling Static website hosting in my S3 website bucket, and set Route53 record set's Alias Target to my S3 website. it's working. But it's not good enough, i want it to deal with multi regions.

I know that Transfer acceleration can auto sync files to other regions so it's faster for other regions. But i don't know how to make it work with Route53. I hear that some people uses CloudFront to do that but i don't quite understand how. And i don't want to manually create buckets in several regions and manually set up for each region

do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by "it's not good enough"? What are you measuring to make this judgement? Are you okay with additional costs for using Amazon CloudFront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to **reduce latency for users worldwide**, then Amazon CloudFront is definitely the way to go.

Amazon CloudFront has [over 100 edge locations](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/) globally, so it has more coverage than merely using AWS regions.

You simply [create a CloudFront distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html), point it to your S3 bucket and then point your domain name to CloudFront.

Whenever somebody accesses your content, CloudFront will retrieve it from S3 and cache it in the edge location closest to that user. Then, other users who want the data will receive it from the local cache. Thus, your website appears fast for many users.

See also: [Amazon CloudFront pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/)

Comment: it sounds quite good. But what is the difference/relationship between CloudFront and the Transfer acceleration setting in S3?

Comment: Amazon CloudFront is a _content distribution service_ that caches data in 100+ locations around the world. Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration is a way of routing requests via the Amazon Network to provide faster performance than via the Internet. It would not be of benefit for your use-case.

Comment: Transfer acceleration also does not support virtual hosting or the static web site features like index documents.  Buckets are accessed via their acceleration endpoint, which is a REST endpoint.

Comment: Cloudfront is only useful when you want to cache content at the edge. In the case of html files you don't want to cache them and now you're back to the same latency problem as cloudfront will then just route to origin s3 bucket.